# How to make Dojo form elements serialize to an array?

Tags: arrays, forms, dojo

I am using Dojo Toolkit and I want form elements to serialize into array, something like this:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" jsId="form">
     <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="id" type="text" value="1"></input>
     <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="array[]" type="text" value="value1"></input>
     <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="array[]" type="text" value="value2"></input>
</div>
```

serialize to:

`{ "id" : 1, "array" : [ "value1", "value2" ] }`

Is it possible?

By the way, I'm using `dojo.toJson(form.get('value'))` for serialzing.

Comment: So you want to get all the values from the form without any information related to what field name maps to what value?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to make a group of controls thar will map to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [dojo.formToObject](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/formToObject.html) or [dojo.formToJson](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/formToJson.html) are what you are looking for?

Comment: By the way, I placed two controls with the same `name` attribute and this form serialized into what I wanted. Thanks!